# Mouse Hover Action-Unable to click hidden Link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click hidden link("WatchBanking") after using move-to-element.

```
WebElement lnkW2yB=dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/personal/ways_to_bank/ways-to-bank-landing']"));
    Actions act=new Actions(dr);
    act.moveToElement(lnkW2yB).build().perform();
    WebElement Span=dr.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Bank with your Watch')]"));
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(dr,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Span));
    act.moveToElement(Span).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
    WebElement lnk=dr.findElement(By.linkText("WatchBanking"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(lnk));
    act.moveToElement(lnk).click(lnk).build().perform();
```

It Moves to the span("Bank with your Watch") and shows link("WatchBanking").
But its not clicking on WatchBanking due to immediate disappearance.
Please give me any solution on this.

Comment: Why doy ou want to move to lnk and click instead call `lnk.click()` directly

Comment: i tried that too..no use @Madhan

Comment: Is it possible to give link to the website or html code of the page

Comment: @SeetharamanS: Try removing that `Thread.sleep(5000L)`. I suspect it's the culprit.

Comment: it was not working when i tried without Thread.sleep(5000L)

Comment: URL:http://www.hdfcbank.com/ @Madhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium sometimes behaves like that only.I would go with `JavascriptExecutor` at times like this.I've repaced Selenium click by Javascript click and it worked perfectly for that site you've mentioned in comment.

Replace the lnk.click() by the following

```
 WebElement lnk = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='WatchBanking']"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(lnk));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", lnk);
```

Comment: @thanks Madhan.Its working fine. Can you tell what does it mean-arguments[0]. Is it something like index of lnk?

Comment: Refer [this](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)  and [this](http://www.ufthelp.com/2014/11/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium.html) the arguments is an array is the way in which the objects array are accessed in the scripts